# Wordpress Permalinks as GET vars from a custom page template (only numbers)

Tags: php, url-rewriting, permalinks, wordpress

I'm trying to add a rewrite rule to pass a var to my page template.

it only excepts numbers in the variables, when I type in characters other then number it directs to 404.
for example: 
this works: `domain.com/reco/9080`
But this doesn't: `domain.com/reco/abcd` (redirects to 404)

This is my code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
        add_rewrite_rule('reco/([^/]*)/?', 'index.php/reco/?b=$1', 'top');
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'add_rewrite_rules');


function query_vars($public_query_vars) {
    $public_query_vars[] = "b";
    return $public_query_vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'query_vars');
```

Cheers!

Comment: See this [Get custom query vars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var#Custom_Query_Vars)

Comment: changed aVars to vars as seen on the link but still no candy :/

Comment: Show us the updated code.

Comment: Updated the code in the question.

Comment: Did you try echoing  `echo get_query_var('b')`?

Comment: OK! it works not, i've updated the code in question... BUT it only excepts numbers in the variables, when I type in characters other then number it directs to 404. for example: this works: http://domain.com/reco/9080/.  But this doesn't: http://domain.com/reco/abcd/ (redirects to 404)

Comment: `reco` is a page (with a custom page template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `get_query_var('b')` which works! apparently wordpress "hogs" the query vars because the website is actually: `index.php?pagename=yourPermalink`.

Also don't try to use variable "s" because wordpress uses this on every page for search purposes.